Search box not integrated with dropdown in JavaScript and HTML
I am new to JS and HTML and am trying to create a webpage in Flask with a dropdown containing a search box that filters the options.
My code looks as such:
<div class="dropdown">
<label for="searchInput">Fund Data </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="searchInput" onkeyup="">
<select id="selectOptions">
    {% for fund in funds %}
     <option value="{{ fund }}">{{ fund }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>

<script>

function showList() {
  document.getElementById("searchInput").classList.toggle("show");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectOptions').selectize({
        sortField: 'text', // Sort options alphabetically
        create: false, // Disable creating new options
        render: {
            option: function (data, escape) {
                 return '<div>' + escape(data.text) + '</div>';
            },
        },
    });
}) ;

</script>

The dropdown looks like this:

I can't seem to get the search box integrated within the dropdown box or have the search box affect the search filter.
Any help would be appreciated and if any more info is needed please let me know.

assuming you have a Flask route rendering this HTML template with funds variable populated with appropriate data :-
must ensure you include the necessary CSS and JavaScript libraries selectize.js & jQuery


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fund Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* add cUSTOM STYLES HERE */
        .dropdown {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
    <label for="searchInput">Fund Data</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="searchInput">
    <select id="selectOptions">
        {% for fund in funds %}
            <option value="{{ fund }}">{{ fund }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectOptions').selectize({
            sortField: 'text', 
            create: false, // Disable creating new options
            render: {
                option: function (data, escape) {
                    return '<div>' + escape(data.text) + '</div>';
                },
            },
        });

        // Add event listener to filter options based on search input
        $('#searchInput').on('input', function () {
            var searchValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $('#selectOptions option').each(function () {
                var optionText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                var showOption = optionText.includes(searchValue);
                $(this).toggle(showOption);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>



